# MediaRecorder: Stop failed -1007

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I have seen questions like that but I have not found solution, so that is why I am asking this.

When I run my app on Alcatel phone and start video recording, everything seems fine, until I press stop button, then I get `RuntimeException`. I read that my video or audio is not in good state, but I can not figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(String name) {

    if (isCameraOpened()) {
        stop();
        start();
    }

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    //int orientation = mCameraInfo.orientation;
    //int orientation = calcCameraRotation(mDisplayOrientation);
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (currentOrientation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    /*if (mCameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (360 - (mCameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360) % 360;
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (mCameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }*/
    if(mCameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        result = (mCameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
       // mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);
    } else{
        result = (mCameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);
    }
    Size pictureSize = null;

    SortedSet<Size> sizes = mPreviewSizes.sizes(mAspectRatio);
    if (sizes == null) { // Not supported
        mAspectRatio = chooseAspectRatio();
        sizes = mPreviewSizes.sizes(mAspectRatio);
    }

    mPictureSizes.clear();

    for (Camera.Size size : mCameraParameters.getSupportedVideoSizes()) {
        mPictureSizes.add(new Size(size.width, size.height));
    }

    Size size = chooseOptimalSize(sizes);

    final Camera.Size currentSize = mCameraParameters.getPictureSize();
    if (currentSize.width != size.getWidth() || currentSize.height != size.getHeight()) {
        // Largest picture size in this ratio
        pictureSize = mPictureSizes.sizes(mAspectRatio).last();
        if (mShowingPreview) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        if(mCameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() != null) {
            mCameraParameters.setPreviewSize(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
        }

        setAutoFocusInternal(mAutoFocus);
        if(mFlash == 1){
            mCameraParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParameters);
        if (mShowingPreview) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    } 

    mCamera.unlock();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    //Set source
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
    if(pictureSize != null) {
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(pictureSize.getWidth(), pictureSize.getHeight());
    }

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(name);


    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        ///mediaRecorder.start();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Then I start MediaRecorder in AsyncTask and this is my stop method.

```
@Override
void stopVideo() {
    if(mFlash == 1){
        mCameraParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    }
    if(isVideoRecording == true) {
        try {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            isVideoRecording = false;
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            getBackgroundHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    File file = getFile(name);
                    if (file != null) {
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,  file.getName());
                        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Taken by All Ears Selfie app");
                        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN,   System.currentTimeMillis());
                        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,  file.length());
                        values.put("_data", file.getAbsolutePath());

                        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
                         cr.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (RuntimeException e){
            Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage());
            File file = getFile(name);
            file.delete();
        }

    }

    if(isCameraOpened()){
        stop();
        start();
    }
}
```

Error:

> 11-15 19:37:09.063 15282-15282/com.allearsapp.allearsselfie E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007
>   11-15 19:37:09.064 15282-15282/com.allearsapp.allearsselfie D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   11-15 19:37:09.089 15282-15282/com.allearsapp.allearsselfie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.allearsapp.allearsselfie, PID: 15282
>                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
>                                                                                     at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.cameraview.Camera1.stopVideo(Camera1.java:314)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.cameraview.CameraView.stopVideo(CameraView.java:64)
>                                                                                     at com.allearsapp.allearsselfie.camera.CameraActivity.stopVideoRecording(CameraActivity.java:410)
>                                                                                     at com.allearsapp.allearsselfie.camera.CameraActivity.access$300(CameraActivity.java:54)
>                                                                                     at com.allearsapp.allearsselfie.camera.CameraActivity$2.onClick(CameraActivity.java:288)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

**EDIT:** I added `OnErrorListener` for Media Recorder and I get this error: 268435556.

Comment: please add the error stack trace

Comment: I have added stack trace.

Comment: are you calling the stop method immediately after start anywhere?

Comment: one thing I see that could cause this error is the preview and video size. I guess, this sizes must be equal, so be sure that `mCameraParameters.setPreviewSize(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());` and `mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(pictureSize.getWidth(), pictureSize.getHeight());` have the same values...

Comment: This error happens only on Alcatel phone. I have tried on Samsung, LG, HTC and Sony. On these phones everything is working fine, but on Alcatel I get this exception.

Comment: I have read that both previewSize and videoSize must be the same size. I set them to be same, but it still fails. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: what is on your CameraActivity line 410, 54 and 288?

Comment: @Zookey Hi, I'm having the exact same error now as yours, did you ever find the solution? The code works fine on some devices but gives me stop failed -1007 on others too.

Comment: Any solution for this? Same issue reported in a Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime with API 8.1, Getting both the -1007 and 268435556 error codes. Finding out what the code 268435556 refers would help a lot, but couldn't find any reference to it.

Comment: @PerracoLabs Did you find what's causing this?

Comment: Yes. This error can be raised by different reasons. In my case happened when a recording had no frames due for being too short, such as start followed by a stop with little duration in between. The solution is quite ugly, to wrap the stop & release in a try/catch. There is no other way, as MediaRecorder has been implemented this way, to throw an error if no enough video frames have been saved when stopped.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the 268435556 error just after starting the video recording and only happened to me on a Huawei device. For me, I managed to solve it just by using a specific video encoder: `mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)`