Screen and Audio Recording is not working when it's in background / switching from native app to other apps
public class ScreenRecordService extends Service {
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener;
    private static final String TAG = "ScreenRecordService";
    private long maxFileSize = NO_SPECIFIED_MAX_SIZE;
    private boolean hasMaxFileBeenReached = false;
    private int mScreenWidth;
    private int mScreenHeight;
    private int mScreenDensity;
    private int mResultCode;
    private Intent mResultData;
    private String path;

    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private String name;
    private int audioBitrate;
    private int audioSamplingRate;
    private static String filePath;
    private static String fileName;
    private int audioSourceAsInt;
    private int videoEncoderAsInt;
    private boolean isCustomSettingsEnabled;
    private int videoFrameRate;
    private int videoBitrate;
    private int outputFormatAsInt;
    private int orientationHint;

    public final static String BUNDLED_LISTENER = "listener";
    private Uri returnedUri = null;
    private Intent mIntent;
    private AudioDeviceCallback audioDeviceCallback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        registerAudioDeviceCallback();
    }

    private void registerAudioDeviceCallback() {
        audioDeviceCallback = new AudioDeviceCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAudioDevicesAdded(AudioDeviceInfo[] addedDevices) {
                // Handle audio devices added (e.g., Bluetooth device connected)
                Log.e("Issue ", "Issue onAudioDevicesAdded");
                handleAudioDeviceChange();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAudioDevicesRemoved(AudioDeviceInfo[] removedDevices) {
                // Handle audio devices removed (e.g., Bluetooth device disconnected)
                Log.e("Issue ", "Issue onAudioDevicesRemoved");
                handleAudioDeviceChange();
            }
        };
        audioManager.registerAudioDeviceCallback(audioDeviceCallback, null);
    }

    private void unregisterAudioDeviceCallback() {
        audioManager.unregisterAudioDeviceCallback(audioDeviceCallback);
    }

    private void handleAudioDeviceChange() {
        // Check if the MediaRecorder is active
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            // Pause or resume the screen recording based on audio focus changes
            int audioFocusState = audioManager.getMode();
            switch (audioFocusState) {
                case AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL:
                    // Resume recording if audio focus is regained
                    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
                        mMediaRecorder.resume();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    // Pause recording if audio focus is temporarily lost
                    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
                        mMediaRecorder.pause();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        boolean isAction = false;

        //Check if there was an action called
        if (intent != null) {
            hasMaxFileBeenReached = false;
            mIntent = intent;
            maxFileSize = intent.getLongExtra(MAX_FILE_SIZE_KEY, NO_SPECIFIED_MAX_SIZE);
            byte[] notificationSmallIcon = intent.getByteArrayExtra("notificationSmallBitmap");
            int notificationSmallVector = intent.getIntExtra("notificationSmallVector", 0);
            String notificationTitle = intent.getStringExtra("notificationTitle");
            String notificationDescription = intent.getStringExtra("notificationDescription");
            String notificationButtonText = intent.getStringExtra("notificationButtonText");
            orientationHint = intent.getIntExtra("orientation", 400);
            mResultCode = intent.getIntExtra("code", -1);
            mResultData = intent.getParcelableExtra("data");
            mScreenWidth = intent.getIntExtra("width", 0);
            mScreenHeight = intent.getIntExtra("height", 0);

            if (intent.getStringExtra("mUri") != null) {
                returnedUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("mUri"));
            }

            if (mScreenHeight == 0 || mScreenWidth == 0) {
                HBRecorderCodecInfo hbRecorderCodecInfo = new HBRecorderCodecInfo();
                hbRecorderCodecInfo.setContext(this);
                mScreenHeight = hbRecorderCodecInfo.getMaxSupportedHeight();
                mScreenWidth = hbRecorderCodecInfo.getMaxSupportedWidth();
            }

            mScreenDensity = intent.getIntExtra("density", 1);
            path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
            name = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
            String audioSource = intent.getStringExtra("audioSource");
            String videoEncoder = intent.getStringExtra("videoEncoder");
            videoFrameRate = intent.getIntExtra("videoFrameRate", 30);
            videoBitrate = intent.getIntExtra("videoBitrate", 40000000);

            if (audioSource != null) {
                setAudioSourceAsInt(audioSource);
            }
            if (videoEncoder != null) {
                setvideoEncoderAsInt(videoEncoder);
            }

            filePath = name;
            audioBitrate = intent.getIntExtra("audioBitrate", 128000);
            audioSamplingRate = intent.getIntExtra("audioSamplingRate", 44100);
            String outputFormat = intent.getStringExtra("outputFormat");
            if (outputFormat != null) {
                setOutputFormatAsInt(outputFormat);
            }

            isCustomSettingsEnabled = intent.getBooleanExtra("enableCustomSettings", false);

            //Set notification notification button text if developer did not
            if (notificationButtonText == null) {
                notificationButtonText = "STOP RECORDING";
            }
            //Set notification bitrate if developer did not
            if (audioBitrate == 0) {
                audioBitrate = 128000;
            }
            //Set notification sampling rate if developer did not
            if (audioSamplingRate == 0) {
                audioSamplingRate = 44100;
            }
            //Set notification title if developer did not
            if (notificationTitle == null || notificationTitle.equals("")) {
                notificationTitle = getString(R.string.stop_recording_notification_title);
            }
            //Set notification description if developer did not
            if (notificationDescription == null || notificationDescription.equals("")) {
                notificationDescription = getString(R.string.stop_recording_notification_message);
            }

            //Notification
            String channelId = "001";
            String channelName = "RecordChannel";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                Notification notification;

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent;

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
                } else {
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                }

                Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action.Builder(
                        Icon.createWithResource(this, android.R.drawable.presence_video_online),
                        notificationButtonText,
                        pendingIntent).build();

                if (notificationSmallIcon != null) {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(notificationSmallIcon, 0, notificationSmallIcon.length);
                    //Modify notification badge
                    notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId).setOngoing(true).setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bmp)).setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setContentText(notificationDescription).addAction(action).build();

                } else if (notificationSmallVector != 0) {
                    notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId).setOngoing(true).setSmallIcon(notificationSmallVector).setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setContentText(notificationDescription).addAction(action).build();
                } else {
                    //Modify notification badge
                    notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId).setOngoing(true).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setContentText(notificationDescription).addAction(action).build();
                }
                startForeground(101231, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION);
            }

            int audioRoutingMode = audioManager.getMode();

            if (audioRoutingMode == AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL) {
                // The device is in normal mode, which means microphone audio should not be blocked or redirected
                Log.e("Issue ", "Issue Audio routing is normal.");
            } else {
                // There might be an issue with audio routing settings
                Log.e("Issue ", "Issue Potential audio routing issue. Please check device settings.");
                // You can display a message to the user informing them to check device audio settings
                // For example:
                Log.e("Issue ", "Issue Potential audio routing issue. Please check device audio settings.");
            }
            afChangeListener = focusChange -> {
                if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
                    Log.e("Issue 1", "Issue Audio focus loss transient");
                    // Pause recording if audio focus is temporarily lost
                    //pauseRecording();
                } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
                    Log.e("Issue 2", "Issue Audio focus gain");
                    // Resume recording if audio focus is regained
                    //resumeRecording();
                } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                    Log.e("Issue 3", "Issue Audio focus loss");
                    AudioFocusRequest audioFocusRequest =
                            new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
                                    .build();
                    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusRequest);
                    // Stop recording if audio focus is permanently lost
                    // stopRecording();
                }
            };

            // Request audio focus
            int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                Log.e("Issue 4", "Issue Audio focus granted");
                // Audio focus granted, start recording
                startRecording(intent);
            } else {
                Log.e("Issue 5", "Failed to request audio focus");
                // Failed to get audio focus, stop the service
                stopSelf();
            }

            if (returnedUri == null) {
                if (path == null) {
                    path = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES));
                }
            }


            //Init MediaProjection
            //}
        } else {
            stopSelf(startId);
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startRecording(Intent intent) {
        initMediaProjection();
        try {
            initRecorder();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        initVirtualDisplay();


      /*  mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == 268435556 && hasMaxFileBeenReached) {
                    // Benign error b/c recording is too short and has no frames. See SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616466/mediarecorder-stop-failed-1007
                    return;
                }
                ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(ScreenRecordService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt(ERROR_KEY, SETTINGS_ERROR);
                bundle.putString(ERROR_REASON_KEY, String.valueOf(what));
                if (receiver != null) {
                    receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
                }
            }
        });*/

       /* mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {
                    hasMaxFileBeenReached = true;
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format(Locale.US, "onInfoListen what : %d | extra %d", what, extra));
                    ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(ScreenRecordService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt(ERROR_KEY, MAX_FILE_SIZE_REACHED_ERROR);
                    bundle.putString(ERROR_REASON_KEY, getString(R.string.max_file_reached));
                    if (receiver != null) {
                        receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
                    }
                }
            }
        });*/

        //Start Recording
        try {
            Log.e("Issue 5", "Issue Record start ended");
            mMediaRecorder.start();
            ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(ScreenRecordService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(ON_START_KEY, ON_START);
            if (receiver != null) {
                receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
            }
            Log.e("Issue 5", "Issue Record start ended");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // From the tests I've done, this can happen if another application is using the mic or if an unsupported video encoder was selected
            ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(ScreenRecordService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(ERROR_KEY, SETTINGS_ERROR);
            bundle.putString(ERROR_REASON_KEY, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            if (receiver != null) {
                receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
            }
        }
    }

/*    //Pause Recording
    private void pauseRecording() {
        mMediaRecorder.pause();
        ResultReceiver receiver = mIntent.getParcelableExtra(ScreenRecordService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ON_PAUSE_KEY, ON_PAUSE);
        if (receiver != null) {
            receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
        }
    }*/

/*    //Resume Recording
    private void resumeRecording() {
        mMediaRecorder.resume();
        ResultReceiver receiver = mIntent.getParcelableExtra(ScreenRecordService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ON_RESUME_KEY, ON_RESUME);
        if (receiver != null) {
            receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
        }
    }*/

    //Set output format as int based on what developer has provided
    //It is important to provide one of the following and nothing else.
    private void setOutputFormatAsInt(String outputFormat) {
        switch (outputFormat) {
            case "DEFAULT":
                outputFormatAsInt = 0;
                break;
            case "THREE_GPP":
                outputFormatAsInt = 1;
                break;
            case "AMR_NB":
                outputFormatAsInt = 3;
                break;
            case "AMR_WB":
                outputFormatAsInt = 4;
                break;
            case "AAC_ADTS":
                outputFormatAsInt = 6;
                break;
            case "MPEG_2_TS":
                outputFormatAsInt = 8;
                break;
            case "WEBM":
                outputFormatAsInt = 9;
                break;
            case "OGG":
                outputFormatAsInt = 11;
                break;
            case "MPEG_4":
            default:
                outputFormatAsInt = 2;
        }
    }

    //Set video encoder as int based on what developer has provided
    //It is important to provide one of the following and nothing else.
    private void setvideoEncoderAsInt(String encoder) {
        switch (encoder) {
            case "DEFAULT":
                videoEncoderAsInt = 0;
                break;
            case "H263":
                videoEncoderAsInt = 1;
                break;
            case "H264":
                videoEncoderAsInt = 2;
                break;
            case "MPEG_4_SP":
                videoEncoderAsInt = 3;
                break;
            case "VP8":
                videoEncoderAsInt = 4;
                break;
            case "HEVC":
                videoEncoderAsInt = 5;
                break;
        }
    }

    //Set audio source as int based on what developer has provided
    //It is important to provide one of the following and nothing else.
    private void setAudioSourceAsInt(String audioSource) {
        switch (audioSource) {
            case "DEFAULT":
                audioSourceAsInt = 0;
                break;
            case "MIC":
                audioSourceAsInt = 1;
                break;
            case "VOICE_UPLINK":
                audioSourceAsInt = 2;
                break;
            case "VOICE_DOWNLINK":
                audioSourceAsInt = 3;
                break;
            case "VOICE_CALL":
                audioSourceAsInt = 4;
                break;
            case "CAMCODER":
                audioSourceAsInt = 5;
                break;
            case "VOICE_RECOGNITION":
                audioSourceAsInt = 6;
                break;
            case "VOICE_COMMUNICATION":
                audioSourceAsInt = 7;
                break;
            case "REMOTE_SUBMIX":
                audioSourceAsInt = 8;
                break;
            case "UNPROCESSED":
                audioSourceAsInt = 9;
                break;
            case "VOICE_PERFORMANCE":
                audioSourceAsInt = 10;
                break;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void initMediaProjection() {
        mMediaProjection = ((MediaProjectionManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE))).getMediaProjection(mResultCode, mResultData);
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(new MediaProjection.Callback() {
            // Nothing
            // We don't use it but register it to avoid runtime error from SDK 34+.
        }, handler);
    }

    //Return the output file path as string
    public static String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    //Return the name of the output file
    public static String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    private void initRecorder() throws Exception {
        Log.e("Issue 5", "Issue Record started");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date curDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String curTime = formatter.format(curDate).replace(" ", "");
        String videoQuality = "HD";
        if (name == null) {
            name = videoQuality + curTime;
        }

        filePath = path + "/" + name + ".mp4";

        fileName = name + ".mp4";

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();


        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

        if (orientationHint != 400) {
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientationHint);
        }

        //if (isAudioEnabled) {
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(audioBitrate);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(audioSamplingRate);
        //}

        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(videoEncoderAsInt);


        if (returnedUri != null) {
            try {
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                FileDescriptor inputPFD = Objects.requireNonNull(contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(returnedUri, "rw")).getFileDescriptor();
                mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(inputPFD);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ResultReceiver receiver = mIntent.getParcelableExtra(ScreenRecordService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(ERROR_REASON_KEY, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                if (receiver != null) {
                    receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
                }
            }
        } else {
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
        }
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight);

        if (!isCustomSettingsEnabled) {
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(5 * mScreenWidth * mScreenHeight);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(60); //after setVideoSource(), setOutFormat()
        } else {
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(videoBitrate);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(videoFrameRate);
        }

        // Catch approaching file limit
        if (maxFileSize > NO_SPECIFIED_MAX_SIZE) {
            mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(maxFileSize); // in bytes
        }

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        Log.e("Issue 5", "Issue Record Prepare");
    }

    private void initVirtualDisplay() {

        Log.e("Issue : ", "" + mMediaRecorder.getSurface());
        mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(TAG, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight, mScreenDensity, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        resetAll();
        callOnComplete();

    }

    private void callOnComplete() {
        if (mIntent != null) {
            ResultReceiver receiver = mIntent.getParcelableExtra(ScreenRecordService.BUNDLED_LISTENER);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(ON_COMPLETE_KEY, ON_COMPLETE);
            if (receiver != null) {
                receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
            }
        }
    }

    private void resetAll() {
        stopForeground(true);
        if (mVirtualDisplay != null) {
            mVirtualDisplay.release();
            mVirtualDisplay = null;
        }
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(null);
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
        }
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            mMediaProjection.stop();
            mMediaProjection = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}

Screen and Audio Recording is not working when it's in background / switching from native app to other apps.
I tried using Audio Playback Capture API but no luck.
Its working in Android 11 and below but above 11 it's failing to record the audio.

Audio source for a submix of audio streams to be presented remotely.
An application can use this audio source to capture a mix of audio streams that should be transmitted to a remote receiver such as a Wifi display. While recording is active, these audio streams are redirected to the remote submix instead of being played on the device speaker or headset.
Certain streams are excluded from the remote submix, including AudioManager#STREAM_RING, AudioManager#STREAM_ALARM, and AudioManager#STREAM_NOTIFICATION. These streams will continue to be presented locally as usual.
Capturing the remote submix audio requires the Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.
Requires Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT

